# Entity framework being accessed on a console project but not on MVC project: ORA 12541: TNS No listener

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oracle, entity-framework, odp.net, tns

i have a class library that has my entity framework model and every thing related to it.
the problem is that i am able to access it in my console project but not on MVC project.

The Client throws an open exception :

[image: i GET THE Connection string successfully]

but when i access any of the entities in context, it throws an Oracle client exception ...

[image: Oracle Client : Failed to Open Connection]

all tasks related to my oracle DB that are not being accessed by entity framework are running all fine on my MVC project 
but when it comes to being accesed by EF ... it throws exception : failed to open underlying connection

what can i do to fix this issue? ... i have tried almost everything described in previous such questions

Comment: That's a connection related error. Do you use the same connection string on both projects? Do you run them on the same machine? If not, the web server may simply have no network access to Oracle, or the Oracle Home may have the wrong configuration. What are you connection strings in both cases?

Comment: the connection strings in both cases are exactly the same

Comment: and yes both the projects are on same machine\

Comment: In command prompt,  echo %oracle_home% > enter. Does it find your oracle_home, if it does, is it the one you desire to use?

Comment: all tasks related to my oracle DB that are not being accessed by entity framework are running all fine on my MVC project

Comment: but when it comes to being accesed by EF ... it throws exception for oracle connection